# REST API abstracting resource attributes?

Tags: json, rest

From the perspective of a consumer, is there any value in abstracting resource attributes to make the fields self-describing? Or should the documentation handle it.

The idea is that each attribute will be wrapped in a more complex object which will provide fieldId, fieldType, and the value. Making each field more descriptive.

In addition, the web service would include another endpoint to further describe each field.

So, instead of the following:

```
{
   "id":123,
   "type":"person",
   "attributes":{
      "name":"John Smith",
      "dateOfBirth":"2000-01-01",
      "ssn":123456789
   }
}
```

The json would look like this:

```
{
   "id":123,
   "type":"person",
   "attributes":[
      {
         "fieldId":"name",
         "dataType":"string",
         "value":"John Smith"
      },
      {
         "fieldId":"dateOfBirth",
         "dataType":"date",
         "value":"2000-01-01"
      },
      {
         "fieldId":"ssn",
         "dataType":"integer",
         "value":123456789
      }
   ],
   "relationships":{
      "dataType":{
         "links":{
            "related":{
               "href":"http://acme.com/ws/dataTypes/"
            }
         },
         "data":[
            {
               "id":"string",
               "type":"dataType"
            },
            {
               "id":"date",
               "type":"dataType"
            },
            {
               "id":"integer",
               "type":"dataType"
            }
         ]
      },
      "field":{
         "links":{
            "related":{
               "href":"http://acme.com/ws/fields/"
            }
         },
         "data":[
            {
               "id":"name",
               "type":"field"
            },
            {
               "id":"dateOfBirth",
               "type":"field"
            },
            {
               "id":"ssn",
               "type":"field"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And then a dataType resource linked to would give some description and/or format:

```
{
   "id":"ssn",
   "type":"field",
   "attributes":{
      "valueType":"string",
      "description":"Social security in the xxx-xx-xxxx format."
   },
   "links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://acme.com/ws/fields/ssn",
         "meta":{
            "httpMethod":"GET"
         }
      }
   }
}

{
   "id":"date",
   "type":"dataType",
   "attributes":{
      "valueType":"string",
      "description":"yyyy-MM-dd"
   },
   "links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://acme.com/ws/dataTypes/date",
         "meta":{
            "httpMethod":"GET"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Or you opt for an existing format: http://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

To answer this `From the perspective of a consumer, is there any value in abstracting resource attributes to make the fields self-describing? Or should the documentation handle it.`

- Based on experience and evaluating multiple api's the api should only send required data. There is no point handling description in response that needs to be taken care by documentation.
- Plus consider the extra amount of data you are sending just to describe the fields
- In addition frontend (say javascript) would need to parse the object, save time by sending only the required data

consider the bandwidth taken by this

```
{
   "id":123,
   "type":"person",
   "attributes":{
      "name":"John Smith",
      "dateOfBirth":"2000-01-01",
      "ssn":123456789
   }
}
```

as compared to this huge data

```
{
   "id":123,
   "type":"person",
   "attributes":[
      {
         "fieldId":"name",
         "dataType":"string",
         "value":"John Smith"
      },
      {
         "fieldId":"dateOfBirth",
         "dataType":"date",
         "value":"2000-01-01"
      },
      {
         "fieldId":"ssn",
         "dataType":"integer",
         "value":123456789
      }
   ],
   "relationships":{
      "dataType":{
         "links":{
            "related":{
               "href":"http://acme.com/ws/dataTypes/"
            }
         },
         "data":[
            {
               "id":"string",
               "type":"dataType"
            },
            {
               "id":"date",
               "type":"dataType"
            },
            {
               "id":"integer",
               "type":"dataType"
            }
         ]
      },
      "field":{
         "links":{
            "related":{
               "href":"http://acme.com/ws/fields/"
            }
         },
         "data":[
            {
               "id":"name",
               "type":"field"
            },
            {
               "id":"dateOfBirth",
               "type":"field"
            },
            {
               "id":"ssn",
               "type":"field"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

From consumer perspective provide them only the required data in response and description in documentation.

And don't make separate call for providing more details, it will be very hard to maintain if you ever change version

Comment: Thanks for sharing your front-end perspective. It makes a lot of sense.